# Passing more than one $Unwind object from java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

The mongo java driver takes var args for aggregate method, I have an API in which `$unwind` objects get's created dynamically and its number is not fixed. how can I pass it through Mongo Java driver aggregate method, as it needs each object to be passed separately. I tried passing putting all the `$unwind` object in a BasicDBList and pass, but it fails. Can someone help me with some work around?

example:

```
db.foo.aggregate({$unwind:items},{$unwind:item2})
```

, but these unwind may vary as it is getting created at runtime.

Comment: you could do separate unwind operations in the pipeline, one after another. But you should realize this is going to be a performance nightmare.

Comment: Performance overhead, cannot do that

Comment: can you give details of how your collection is structured? is item2 a list in items? if items and item2 are separate lists in your collection, why would you need to unwind both items and item2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to create a BasicDBList. This is how it works:

```
List<DBObject> unwindItems = new ArrayList<>();

if(<item2 is not null>){ //pseudo code
  DBObject unwindItem1 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$item1");
  unwindItems.add(unwindItem1);
}
if(<item2 is not null>){ //pseudo code
  DBObject unwindItem2 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$item2");
  unwindItems.add(unwindItem2);
}
//add any other dbObject in the list, it need not be an unwind operation, it could be match, project, group etc.

DBObject command = new BasicDBObject("aggregate", "foo");
command.put("pipeline", dbObjects);
```